# Issue in accessing HbaseConfiguration method using scala

Tags: scala, hbase, spark-streaming

I am trying to implement spark streaming for adding kafka topics to hbase.when I am implementing using Maven in scala eclipse,I came across below issue

I imported the below line
 "import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration,HTableDescriptor,HColumnDescriptor}"

val hConf = new HBaseConfiguration()

until this point there were no errors,but on the next line when I am trying to set Config properties like below

hConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost:2182")

I am getting the error "value set is not a member of org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration"

---

I am just following the above link

https://acadgild.com/blog/building-a-real-time-application-using-kafka-and-spark

for implementing this

---

Could you please let me know how to resolve this error.

Regards,
Sudheer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:As my hadoop jars in the maven got corrupted.Simply I removed the files under "C:\Users\user1.m2\repository\org\apache\hadoop".Again I rebuild the project to add the dependencies.Then I am able to access the configuration from hadoop dependencies....Hope it helps someone!